# Which verb should I use to activate a command?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, verbs

I am writing a program. There are some buttons that will be used to control a distant device (i.e. : Reset).

I cannot create a single label for each button. Hence, I am looking for a generic word, a verb, to write on every button.
That verb has to tell the user something like "pressing that button will do something on the distant device" (the thing is written on the side of the button, pressing it will activate the action).
I want it to make aware the user that an action is going to happen.

Note that these actions take a few milliseconds to achieve.

I am currently using "Run", but it is not fine. Something like "Execute", "GO" or "Activate" is more accurate, but still not what I want. "Achieve" is even closer. "Perform" is pretty much it, but I would like some more opinions / suggestions.

Comment: How about *initiate*?

Comment: I am going to think about it. I think it sounds like the action is going to take a long time, doesn't it? I forgot to mention that most of these actions will only take a few milliseconds.

Comment: It doesn't actually mention about how long the action is going to take.

Comment: Initiate is great, but it is only about triggering the action. I want the user to think the button itself will perform it, even though it is not what is going to happen. By the way, "perform" sounds good to me. Any opinion?

Comment: What will it do exactly?

Comment: I would like to use one word for all of the actions. I cannot know everything it will do and I cannot create a single word for each action. So, "it will do many things" is the best answer I can provide you. If it helps you, think about a robot that will open a window, switch on the lights, ... I am looking for a single word to say it is going to do "that action" ("that action" being written on the side of the button).

Comment: Is the point that you want to make clear that the action is happening on a remote device? Or simply that some action will happen? If all the buttons cause an action to happen, then any word that indicates "make something happen" would appear on every button, and thus would seem pretty redundant and pointless. Like if I have a button that causes a reset, I label it "Reset". That's all you need. Saying "Execute Reset" or "Initiate Reset" or whatever is just extra words that add nothing. Maybe I'm missing the point of the question.

Comment: The point is to make the user aware that an action will happen. I cannot create a single label for each of the buttons. They will change according to the device and there are many, many potential devices. So yes, it is sometimes redundant but that redundancy is not a problem.

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic here, but you may get better results in the User Experience SE.

Comment: I agree with @Era - we can give you word suggestions, but the [ux.se] folks may have suggestions on presenting the buttons that may be far easier for the user. If you write your question a little differently (don't ask for a word but some advice on presenting the buttons) I don't think it would be considered cross-posting, so you could leave this one open.

Comment: A minor correction: **software** is a non-count noun.  You can *write software* or *write a program*, but you can't *write a software*.

Comment: Because you seem to not know what it's gonna do, I wouldn't write anything on the button, if I were in your position. Maybe I will give it a color, and in the manual write something like, "Press the Green button to command the robot to perform the assigned action." An intuitive icon on the button may be helpful, too.

Comment: @Stangdon - I like that approach to the world ("_software is a non-count noun_") so much that I upvoted your comment.  Unfortunately, it isn't always adhered to.  _"A software that"_ is unpleasantly common ( https://www.google.com/#q=%22a+software+that%22 ) and becoming more so: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+software+that&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=2&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ca%20software%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20software%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BA%20software%20that%3B%2Cc0

Comment: In my U.S. public sector industry the engineers don't say "a software," but the management does.

Comment: @Adam - That's depressing.  I wonder if the management goes to the furniture store to buy "a furniture" too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think **Run Command** might work. And you could accompany it with a tooltip saying something like *Send a command to the device*.